Load a set of Jenkins Secretes into Environment Variables
I'm building & testing a Spring application via the Jenkins pipeline. When building and testing it for e.g. test environment, I have to provide it with a set of env variables for the test environment, which I currently store in the secrets - I don't want them public or plain text.
Meaning, I'm trying to load a whole set of Jenkins Secrets into Environment variables by providing just one Jenkins parameter, say: params.environment = test -
In that case, I would like to load all the secrets with the prefix "test" into env vars.
The end goal would be that I don't have to edit Jenkins scripts every time I need to add a new env var for building the app. I could add a new "test" secret to the Jenkins secrets and the script would load the new secret along with all the old ones on the next run.

Do you have more than one environment?

Yes I do, I could have "develop", "stage", etc

I suppose it's possible to create different credentials domains for different environments and pass all the credentials from a domain. Your pipeline would look something like this
@Library('shared-lib') _
pipeline {
  agent {label 'built-in'}
  stages {
    stage('Hello') {
      steps {
        withDomainSecrets('develop') {
          sh 'env|sort'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

And your shared library should have a withDomainSecrets.groovy file looking something like this
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.StringCredentials

def call(String domainName, Closure body) {
  withCredentials(
    SystemCredentialsProvider.instance.domainCredentialsMap
    .find { it.key.name == domainName }.value
    .findResults { credential ->
      switch(credential.class) {
        case StringCredentials:
          return string(credentialsId: credential.id, variable: credential.id)
      }
    }
  ) {
    body()
  }
}

A couple of caveats:

Your credential ids should be valid environment variable names
You would still need to modify the call method if you want to add more credential types

